# problem while using local storage in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

What i am trying to do-
i am setting (again) some key (which are set at some other point in my application i.e, Login )value pairs in local storage when a function is called.
similar to reset password.
and it works fine just the problem is that when on the same page if i access those items after resetting them it shows undefined. but when i do login again those values are changed and shows the latest values.

i also tried running on android device and in ionic serve and ionic lab . it never worked.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
 public navParams: NavParams,
 public apiConnect:ApiIntegrationProvider,
 public loadingCtrl:LoadingController,
 public toastCtrl:ToastController,
  public storage: Storage) {

console.log(this.user_name)
this.fetchProfile();
 }

fetchProfile(){
this.user_role=localStorage.getItem("userRole");
this.user_name=localStorage.getItem("userName");
this.user_Email=localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
this.user_Mobile=localStorage.getItem("userMobile");
this.user_Avatar=localStorage.getItem("userAvatar");
this.user_Language=localStorage.getItem("userLanguage");
this.company_name=localStorage.getItem("companyName");
this.company_email=localStorage.getItem("companyEmail");
this.company_punch=localStorage.getItem("companyPunch");
this.company_url=localStorage.getItem("companyUrl");
console.log("user data")
console.log("company name", this.company_name,"email",this.company_email,"punch",this.company_punch,"website", this.company_url,"language", this.user_Language);
if(this.user_Language=='pt'){
  this.language="Portuguese"
}else{
  this.language="English"
}
if(this.user_role=='25'){ 
this.role='Inspector';

}else if(this.user_role=='35'){
this.role='Team Lead';
 }else if(this.user_role=='45'){
 this.role='Moderator';
}else if(this.user_role=='55'){
  this.role='Administrator';
}else if(this.user_role=='65'){
  this.role='Super Administrator';
}

}




 editProfile(){
console.log(this.decideEditProfile);
console.log("edit profile function")
this.decideEditProfile=true;

  }



  SaveProfile(){
    console.log(this.decideEditProfile);
    console.log("edit profile function")
    this.decideEditProfile=false;
    this.useredit();
  }

   ionViewDidLoad() {

  console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');

  }
  showToast(position: string) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: this.editStatus.message,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    toast.present(toast);
  }
  useredit() {
    const loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait...",
      duration: 3000
    });
    loader.present();
    let passingValue = {
      "user_id": '3',
      "inputName": 'James Red',
      "inputEmail":'moderator@gmail.com.in',
      "inputPassword":'123456'
    }
     this.apiConnect.postEditProfile( 
  JSON.stringify(passingValue)).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log("login api "+JSON.stringify(data));

  this.editStatus = data;
  if (this.editStatus.status == "success") {
    localStorage.removeItem("userName");
    localStorage.removeItem("userEmail");
    localStorage.removeItem("userMobile");
    localStorage.removeItem("userAvatar");
    localStorage.removeItem("userLanguage");
    localStorage.setItem("userName",this.editStatus.Profile.fullName);
    localStorage.setItem("userEmail",this.editStatus.Profile.emailAddress);
    localStorage.setItem("userMobile",this.editStatus.Profile.mobile);
    localStorage.setItem("userAvatar",this.editStatus.Profile.avatar);
    localStorage.setItem("userLanguage",this.editStatus.Profile.languagePreference);

    this.showToast('top');
    this.navCtrl.push("DashBoardPage");
  }
  else {

    this.showToast('top');
  }
  loader.dismiss();
})
```

}

Comment: what is the data coming in `this.editStatus.Profile.fullName`? Is it `null` or `empty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question you are trying to say that even after updating the `localstorage` you are getting the old value or `undefined`.
So it might be possible that the data which you are returning may be null or empty. You have to carefully debug your application because `localstorage` do not work this same way. Do a console test.

Also in this piece of code :

```
if (this.editStatus.status == "success") {
    localStorage.removeItem("userName");
    localStorage.removeItem("userEmail");
    localStorage.removeItem("userMobile");
    localStorage.removeItem("userAvatar");
    localStorage.removeItem("userLanguage");
    localStorage.setItem("userName",this.editStatus.Profile.fullName);
    localStorage.setItem("userEmail",this.editStatus.Profile.emailAddress);
    localStorage.setItem("userMobile",this.editStatus.Profile.mobile);
    localStorage.setItem("userAvatar",this.editStatus.Profile.avatar);
    localStorage.setItem("userLanguage",this.editStatus.Profile.languagePreference);

    this.showToast('top');
    this.navCtrl.push("DashBoardPage");
  }
```

You do not have to remove the items unnecessarily you can just set the `localstorage` and the old values will be replaced by the new values.

I hope this helps you. Thanks!